# I can hear my computer, Why is that

Tags: audio, sound-card, interference, mixer

My computer is wired to my audiomixer and then to my headphones. If i turn the volume off my mixer up i can literately hear my computer(if my computer is'nt playing audio ofcourse). I can hear  it when i maximize or minimize a window. I can hear my mouse hovering over a link in a browser,.. 
I have multiple soundcards, and only the one on my mainbord gives me this "interference"
How can it be that i can hear software? Is there anyone here that can give me an explanation.

Comment: What do you mean you hear "software".  The actions you describe as generating sounds isn't all that strange.

Comment: No it are not sounds, but its noise.

Comment: What sort of connection does your headphones use exactly?  It seems you don't actually want a solution which means this question will simply lead to extended discussion about the possible causes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work part time in a recording studio, and this is very common on computers with no external sound card, audio processor or recording interface.

Electrical interference can occur in or around the motherboard, tower, cables, fans and pretty much anything electrical in or connected to your computer. This interference can manifest itself in scratching or buzzing in audio equipment when speakers or headphones are connected.

If you want to solve the problem, I would see if your mixer, speaker or headphones cables are near any other electrical cable or device. If they aren't I would suggest getting a better external sound card, like a USB one, which should eliminate the interference.

Some sound cards or audio interfaces advertise their cables as being "noise-shielded". While sometimes this is just "hype" language, investing in good quality equipment and cables should reduce or eliminate the noise.

Answer (score 1):

My computer do this also. I suppose you plug your headphones in the front panel. Then this is because of the lack of the proper insulation of the cable which go to the front audio panel, so it is got some interference from other electricity components.

You could prevent it by set the cable a position when nothing touch it. Other solution is buying a better computer case with better built-in audio panel.

Comment: I don't want a solution to this(i can just plug in in another audio card):-) I'm just hoping for an explanation. Btw, its not plugged in in the frontpanel.

Comment: Interference is the explanation :)